# LINQ- Select linq from string array

Tags: c#, linq

How apply linq select to string array in C#

ex :

```
string[] result;
...
result.Select(..)
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Could you please explain me more in detail?

Comment: What is the problem? Does that code not compile? Are you `using System.Linq`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Probably you missed the line:
using System.Linq;

Answer (score 9):

You pass in a *lambda* function that tells the system what you want to *do* with each string.

```
string[] result;
...
var newList = result.Select(s => {do something with s});
```

The function can do most anything that takes a string as an input and returns a value - it doesn't even have to return a string!  For example, if the strings contained numeric characters, you could return a collection of numbers:

```
IEnumerable<int> newList = result.Select(s => int.Parse(s));
```

Note that the original array *will not be changed*.